# getting complete URI address in JSF

Tags: jsf

How can I get a complete URI address `( http:// .../ ../.)` in JSF using FacesContext ?

Comment: I meant getting user's URI address

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
public String getRequestUrl()
{
    Object request = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest)
    {
        String requestedUrl = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString();
        return requestedUrl;
    }

    return "";
}
```

P.s., since you are new to StackOverflow, please vote my answer up and accept if it helped.